# Prevent HAML from rendering newline in produced HTML file

Tags: html, ruby, haml

I have this HAML code:

```
%p
    This page is for our staff. If you came here by mistake,
    %a(href="index.html") you can go back
    \.
```

The isolated `\.` is there because I don't want the full-stop (.) to be part of the link.

This almost works but there is a space between `back` and `.`; naturally, HAML is inserting the newline in the HAML source code in the HTML rendered file.

In other words, this is the HTML produced:

```
<p>
    This page is for our staff. If you came here by mistake,
    <a href="index.html">you can go back</a>
    . <!-- I want the period to be on the previous line -->
</p>
```

Because words inside the `<p>` tag are separated by a space, there is a space between `back` and `.`. How can I remove this space?

I found one way to do this, but it is ugly (or I won't have asked this question):

```
%p
    This page is for our staff. If you came here by mistake,
    %a(href="index.html") you can go back
    %span>\.
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAML accepts plain html, so you could write:

```
%p
    This page is for our staff. If you came here by mistake,
    <a href="index.html">you can go back</a>.
```

Which will give you the output you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`succeed`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#helper-methods) helper for this, although it reads a little funny:

```
= succeed '.' do 
  %a(href="index.html") you can go back
```

Will produce:

```
<a href="index.html">you can go back</a>.\n
```

So full example would be like:

```
%p
  This page is for our staff. If you came here by mistake,
  = succeed "." do 
    %a(href="index.html") you can go back
```

Rendered Output:

```
<p>
This page is for our staff. If you came here by mistake,
<a href='index.html'>you can go back</a>.
</p>
```